# How do I initiate a chat?

Tags: discussion, chat

I would like to initiate a chat related to https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/21055/grandsons-behaviour/21300?noredirect=1#comment40428_21300

I would not like to analyze the OP in the thread, but I would like to say to @Erica (who commented that she was confused by something I wrote in my answer):

*The "Lucky to have" opener was intended to acknowledge and validate the OP's feelings and hard work.*

*Clarification: I'm not suggesting she spend less time with her grandson, but I am suggesting she spend less time in a primary caregiver role, and more time having fun with him.  As primary caregiver, things are not working very well at the moment, perhaps because not enough time is being spent building a relationship with the little boy -- which I believe is the basis of all successful discipline.*

*I want the little boy to look forward to seeing his grandmother again.  She deserves that.*

*I think this is still providing support -- but I do acknowledge that it would amount to providing less unpaid babysitting.*

*Hopefully, later on, after working on their relationship in a lower stress context, babysitting hours can be expanded once again.*

My meta question is, how do I put these comments into a Chat (preferably associated with the original thread)?

Answer (score 3):

If you go to chat.stackexchange.com and go to the Site tab, you see an option to create a new room. Once you have done this you can use the URL for that room.

However, in this instance, I don't think it is your best plan.

Your line up there:

> The "Lucky to have" opener was intended to acknowledge and validate the OP's feelings and hard work.

Is just not needed. It is filler that doesn't contribute to the post, so the edit helped clear that bit out the way.

SE is all about collaborative work, and anyone with the required rep can improve posts - it really doesn't require a lot of conversation to and fro. All that does, and the reason I suggest a chat room just for this is a waste of effort, is that it just takes up even more of everyone's time.

If you absolutely feel you must leave those comments in chat, please use the normal parenting chat room, don't create a new one.

Comment: I finally discovered the Parenting Chat Room!  Thank you, something you said in your answer made me take a closer look, and I found "the" parenting chat room.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying, that it is not necessary to create a special room for a specific chat topic.